# Use bootstrap date picker with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Can I use the bootstrap 3 date picker [component](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) with angular?

I tried following [this](http://cdmckay.org/blog/2014/12/08/how-to-create-an-angular-directive-for-eonasdans-bootstrap-datetime-picker/) tutorial but I failed with only the input appearing but no calendar when clicked.

**EDIT:**
This [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waLEqM) somewhat resembles my actual code, and what I wanted was to add the datetime picker. I know there are a few date pickers for angular but the one I linked fits better with my design I believe.

```
angular.module('materialApp.directives')
    .directive('psDatetimePicker', function (moment) {
        var format = 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A';
```

Have I done any obvious mistakes?

Comment: Can you show the code or create a fiddle?

Comment: I cannot because the code on itself is too big, containing various other things. I'll try to create a fiddle.

Comment: @tibzon maybe the pen helps.

Comment: Would suggest doing this on a plnkr.   Since your thing is named material app you might be interested in the date/time picker I made here too http://shusain.github.io/itDateTimePicker/ could use a hand hammering out a few bugs on it but it was built based on the material design one on my phone for my own apps.

Comment: I actually came across your implementation but the name kinda stuck there, and a date picker of that type does not fit very well with the rest of the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **ui-bootstrap's**(AngularJS module) datepicker. [Reference here.](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: I've seen this component but I wanted it to have time too. Plus the one I showed looks a little bit better I think.

Comment: Well, you can use timepicker with date picker ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try bootstrap-datepicker

> github repo : https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker
>
> Demo : http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Try this for date with time :

> https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: The component you are suggesting is the one I am trying to use and linked in my question. The thing is that it is not for angular.

Comment: It can be used with angular also , You just have to call  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker(); function .

Comment: Can you create an example of that, because i need to use a controller and I thought that the tutorial I linked was the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the [documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/) for your bootstrap timepicker and without seeing your code - I would guess you don't have everything loaded. Make sure you've included everything required... especially the bootstrap.js to include collapse... and you'd still need to use the bootstrap [datetimepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) mentioned by Tarun.

> > Minimal Requirements
>
> ```
> jQuery
> Moment.js
> Bootstrap.js (transition and collapse are required if you're not using the full Bootstrap)
> Bootstrap Datepicker script
> Bootstrap CSS
> Bootstrap Datepicker CSS
> Locales: Moment's locale files are here
> ```

```
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
</head>
```

Comment: I added all the requirements though, and I simply copy pasted the directive from the linked tutorial.

Comment: Well that's why... that isn't the complete directive.  In this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/0Ltv25o8/)  you can see they are loading the complete directive (https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js) in the external resources.  I wouldn't follow the tutorial but instead follow the actual documentation for the directive.

Comment: The fiddle you provided even though uses the component I want, has no connection with angular from what I can see.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke, the directive in the tutorial is used to implement the link datetimepicker in the fiddle.  You have to have both for the directive from the tutorial to work properly.